# Install Windows 7 64bit from USB drive in UEFI mode

Tags: windows-7, usb, uefi

I got a Lenovo Ideapad Y580 with Windows 8 and I want to install Windows 7 on it.
I followed the instructions on [this link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/186875-uefi-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-install-windows-7-a.html) to create a UEFI Windows 7 Install USB flash drive - but it does not work.

I followed the steps:

1. Format my 4 GB USB flash drive to FAT32
2. Copy the Windows 7 64 SP1 ISO contents to the flash drive
3. copy `/efi/microsoft/boot` to `/efi/boot`
4. find the *bootmgfw.egi* in install.wim, copy to the newly copied /efi/boot and rename it to bootx64.efi
5. restart, enter the boot menu and select USB flash drive in the UEFI boot menu list

But after I select the USB drive and the initial loading windows progress bar finished, it hangs at the "Starting Windows" screen.

Is there something wrong with my steps?

Comment: I heard that Windows7 USB/DVD Download Tool format the primary partition on usb to ntfs not fat32, so it may not work with UEFI, is that true?

Comment: Tried the Windows 7 Download Tool. The UEFI mode can not find the device, because Windows 7 Download Tool format the flash drive to NTFS.

Comment: I tried win8 iso with fat32 usb flash drive, it has no problem. But I can not get win7 work through, as I described in this post.