# Original Windows 7 installation disk on EFI computer

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, efi

I have an original Windows 7 64-bit installation disc, but with my new computer (Cloud Project AIR-X1 based upon Intel Atom Z3735) I can't boot from it. It's because the CD is not EFI-compatible.
My EFI firmware doesn't seem to have a "legacy" option. Well, it has an item like "EFI Device First" that would place the EFI or legacy device first in the list.

Still my CD is not shown in the boot menu.
The firmware says: "InsydeH20 v. 5"

Is there a way to "convert" my installation disc to EFI-compatible? Or it can be (legally!) download somewhere given that I have a valid license (not OEM)?

Comment: The Windows 7 CDROM should (is?) EFI capable. It need manual intervention if you turn this iso into an USB installation medium (moving bootx64.efi), but from the disk it should just work.

Comment: I think it's an Atom with 32 bit EFI. Yes, I disabled secure boot. Right now I'm trying to making a USB bootable drive following this instructions: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/boardsandkits/Windows-7-UEFI-Installation.pdf

Comment: The USB3 fix in that doc is in case you are trying to use an USB3 port. For the rest I used this method descibed here https://superuser.com/questions/527708/install-windows-7-64bit-from-usb-drive-in-uefi-mode, though I used an existing win7 x64 install rather than extracting the file from install.wim).  This far it has worked on every single computer which supports old fashioned graphics calls (and not just modern GOP interface. But then windows would succesfully start to install and crash later during installation).

Comment: Windows 7 **does not** support UEFI mode with 32-bit UEFI kernels.  You can't boot a 64-bit installation of Windows 7 with a 32-bit UEFI firmware.

Comment: @Ramhound bottom line: I **cannot** install my original Windows 7 on this hardware, do I understand correctly?

Comment: You had a Windows 7 64-bit installation installed but it wasn’t installed in UEFI mode but Legacy Mode thus MBR was used instead of GOT.  So you can install it again but not while in UEFI mode

Comment: Please post the make and specific model of you new computer for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 64-bit will not boot from a 32-bit EFI firmware. The Windows architecture must match the UEFI architecture. That is one of the basic design assumptions for UEFI.

P.S. Full disclosure - There are some hacks to enable a 64-bit OS to boot on 32-bit EFI firmware.

Comment: Got it. But why manufacturers would provide 32-bit EFI on a 64-bit processor?

Comment: @Mark Profit margin.  Why it was done it entirely out of scope.  Your hardware doesn’t support what you want.  So get different hardware.